# How should I begin writing a story for a comic strip?

Tags: structure, comics, story

I would like to draw a comic strip, but I need a story. I would prefer a realistic one (historic or not).

I was wondering if you have any advice for how to approach the writing of a story for comic strips such as [this one](https://www.babelio.com/livres/Renard-Alpha-tome-1--Lechange/164836).

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! We have a [tag:comics] tag for questions about writing comics (which I guess is what you meant by "cartoons") - you may wish to browse the questions under that tag to see if they help you.

Comment: That question is really much too vague. What exactly are you struggling with? Do you have an idea for a story? Do you know how to develop the plot and the characters? Do you know the format for a comic script? –– If you want a general introduction into writing for comics, pick up any book on that topic and read it. A good one is *Alan Moore's Writing for Comics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the first advice is - have a story to tell.

A story that you believe the audience should hear, that you personally want to make sure they don't miss.

Without a story that needs told, any storytelling is pointless. (Regardless of medium and form.)

Once you know what you want to say, figuring out how is the less fundamental part.

Or maybe it doesn't have to be you who has a story to tell. A lot of comics are writer-artist collaborations. If you're more interested in doing the artwork, you might like to pair up with a writer and then the story would be their problem, not yours.

Unfortunately there's nothing I can tell you about how to find a comics writer to work with.

Comment: Thank you ! (I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer...)